# How to fix security error when debugging iOS app to iOS Device

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

I'm trying to debug an app to my iOS Device with the new update in Xcode (7.1), but I keep getting a security error. How do I fix this? I've looked everywhere in Settings, and can't seem to be able to fix it. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Do you have restriction turned on: Preferences, General, Restrictions. Hint, there is a search field at the top of Settings, just entering "device" or "management" will find two possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go to Settings - General - Profiles - tap on your Profile - tap on
>   Trust button.

If the option to view **Profiles** is **not viewable** do the following from Xcode.

- Open Xcode 7.
- Go to window, devices.
- Select your device.
- Delete all of the profiles loaded on the device. Delete the old app on your device.
- Clean and rebuild the app to your device.

Comment: Thanks so much! That did it!